# Free jqGrid and ace admin template header display issue

Tags: jqgrid

This is an another issue using admin template; there is more detail [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553999/jqgrid-free-and-ace-admin-template-integration).

Group heading has extra vertical line displayed.

After investigating, I found out what is wrong with the header display, looking with developer tool, the attribute **ui-row-ltr** if deleted, 
fix the display.

The fix was to remove in developer tools to have the line like below.

How can we override ace CSS not to declare the property **"ui-row-ltr"** in the below line or something that jqgfirstrow does not do anything?

```
tr class="ui-widget-content jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto"
```

Ideally if it does not have the attribute ui-row-ltr, then no more header display problem.

```
<table id="grid-table" tabindex="0" role="presentation" aria-labelledby="gbox_grid-table" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" style="width: 1px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgfirstrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" style="height:auto">
...

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Can we override this attribute?

Comment: Could you provide **the demo** (in JSFiddle for example) which reproduces the problem? You write in your question about some "ace css", but I answered on your previous question that one don't need and "ace css" at all and to insert *your custom CSS rules* instead, which makes the same (or close) look as ACE template do. The CSS windows of http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jj0qbhbt/ (see my previous question) contains an example of such CSS settings. **Which CSS settings uses you?** Could you display a picture, which demonstrates the problem, which you need to solve?

Comment: Class `ui-row-ltr` in `<tr>` should make no problems. It's really required. Probably you have some conflict in CSS rule from `ui.jqgrid.cs` (like [this one](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.4/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L458-L464)) and *some other* CSS (from Bootstrap or your custom CSS settings) which is unknown for me till you provide the demo, which uses all the CSS together in some specific order so that one can see the problem.

Comment: I found the fix , thanks to your reply pointing me to the ui.jqgrid.css. Thus, I've added the below line, and no more header issue: **.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv tr.ui-row-ltr > td { padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; }**. It's very hard to reprodue the problem in a demo using JSFiddle. In my app, I need the ace.min.css due to the entire main page using it. Thanks again Oleg, much appreciated for pointers which I sometimes misunderstood. I'll made some final test and marked it solved.

Comment: It's a good news. You are welcome! I'd recommend you to verify that you include `ui.jqgrid.css` **after** `ace.min.css`. It will force the usage of correct free jqGrid rules if both `ui.jqgrid.css` and `ace.min.css` defines close rules.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the best practice tip!